# Highest value of int type in C/C++. Why can't I calculate it correctly in this example?

Tags: c++, c, integer, max, limits

In the example program to print out the powers of 2 up to the highest possible integer value I run into a confusing result.

The integer variables are signed, so the highest bit is used for the sign. On my machine the size of an integer is 4 bytes, i.e. 32 bits. I expected the highest possible integer value to be 2^31.

Confusing for me is the following:
The highest integer value I can calculate is 2^30.
The result shows that 2^31 is the minimum integer value and not the maximum.
Moreover, 2^32 should exceed the max integer value and I expected an unpredicable result. Instead it is 0.

### Example in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
    int exp;
    int pow = 1;

    for (exp = 0; exp < 33; exp++) {
        printf("2 to the power of %d is %d\n", exp, pow);
        pow *= 2;
    }

    printf("%d\n", INT_MIN);
    printf("%d\n", INT_MAX);

    return 0;
}
```

### Example in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int pow = 1;

    for (int exp = 0; exp < 33; exp++) {
        cout << "2 to the power of " << exp << " is " << pow << endl;
        pow *= 2;
    }

    int imin = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(); // minimum value
    int imax = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    cout << imin << endl;
    cout << imax << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### Output is in both examples the same:

```
2 to the power of 0 is 1
2 to the power of 1 is 2
2 to the power of 2 is 4
2 to the power of 3 is 8
2 to the power of 4 is 16
2 to the power of 5 is 32
2 to the power of 6 is 64
2 to the power of 7 is 128
2 to the power of 8 is 256
2 to the power of 9 is 512
2 to the power of 10 is 1024
2 to the power of 11 is 2048
2 to the power of 12 is 4096
2 to the power of 13 is 8192
2 to the power of 14 is 16384
2 to the power of 15 is 32768
2 to the power of 16 is 65536
2 to the power of 17 is 131072
2 to the power of 18 is 262144
2 to the power of 19 is 524288
2 to the power of 20 is 1048576
2 to the power of 21 is 2097152
2 to the power of 22 is 4194304
2 to the power of 23 is 8388608
2 to the power of 24 is 16777216
2 to the power of 25 is 33554432
2 to the power of 26 is 67108864
2 to the power of 27 is 134217728
2 to the power of 28 is 268435456
2 to the power of 29 is 536870912
2 to the power of 30 is 1073741824
2 to the power of 31 is -2147483648
2 to the power of 32 is 0
-2147483648
2147483647
```

Comment: You do realize 2^32 is not in range ? How about playing with `unsigned int`, then looking into what overflow and -ve and undefined behavior  means ?

Comment: Think about what is the largest value you can store in 1 bit. It's not 2^1=2 is it. It is 1 = 2^1-1. Similarly the largest value you can store in 31 bits is 2^31-1. And the reason two`s complement can store -2^31 is that the negative numbers do not include 0.

Comment: This does not print the maximum possible value, just as multiplying by powers of 10 does not show the maximum value for *n* digits: `1`, `10`, `100`, `1000` ... (which should be `9`, `99`, `999`, `9999` ..)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Signed Integer Overflow.

It's undefined behavior. So getting `0` is a perfectly valid undefined result.

#### The largest integer in an `int`.

It's `2^31 - 1`, not `2^31`. Note that `INT_MAX` is an odd number.

#### Two's Complement

Most systems that you will ever encounter won't use [Signed Magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation) to represent signed numbers. Instead they will use [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: It's 2^31-1 *if* `int` is 32 bits (and has no padding bits).

Answer (score 1):

Performing pow*=2 is like pow<<=1.
It explains perfectly the behavior you see.
When your initial 1 is shifted left 31 times, it lies in the sign bit of the integer. It represents the minimum int value.
When you shift it once more it overflows and it stays only 32 zero bits in the integer, so you get 0.